# How to mock hasNext with high amount of returns

Tags: java, junit, mockito

For my test I need to mock the hasNext() method of my cursos. However to fully test my code i need 250 iterations to send to a bulkRequest. Therefore i need 250 x true and 1 x false at the end.

I created a boolean array filled with 250 true's and 1 false

what i got

```
@Mock
private Cursor<Record> cursor;

public void myTest(){
  when(cursor.hasNext()).thenReturn(true, false);
}
```

but now I need 250 conditions for cursor
so i created a boolean Array but obvoiusly it doesn't compile

```
final boolean[] cursorsResponses = fillCursors();
when(cursor.hasNext()).thenReturn(cursorsResponses);
```

Comment: Create a class that has a `hasNext()` method and all the internal state/logic you want, then call it at `thenReturn`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in your case:

```
when(cursor.hasNext()).thenAnswer(new Answer() {
   private int count = 0;

   public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
        return (count++ < 250);
   }
});
```